# Vim: how to insert a character like '\' automatically when auto wrap a line?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, word-wrap, text-width

Suppose I :set tw=5, when wrapping the following 'long' line:

```
a = b + c
```

It becomes:

```
a = b
+ c
```

Yet I want it to be:

```
a = b \
+ c
```

Or even better if a smart indent is inserted on the next line, like this:

```
a = b \
  + c
```

How do I do that?

Comment: doesn't always work for me but `set showbreak` may help

Comment: Do you want it to actually be inserted into the file, or just shown on the screen?

Comment: I want it to be inserted into the file, because I am writing python in which the compiler would take two lines as one if '\' is used. Thanks!